# Clarification of wording in matter phases

Tags: states-of-matter

I read on the internet a sentence that went:

> The reactions can be done in the gaseous phase dispersed in liquids.

Does this mean that the reactions can occur to the participants while they are in a gaseous form, and are dispersed in liquids? So the participants are not liquid, but are dispersed in liquids while are in gaseous form?

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear indeed. More context would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is one of possible methods, in. e.g., a bubble column.

See an example here https://books.google.pl/books?id=VRV2kn9IMZUC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=The+reactions+can+be+done+in+the+gaseous+phase+dispersed+in+liquids.&source=bl&ots=PqQRxi_XAg&sig=25LYf_p-frxB3gXAtOXnLpEY2EU&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47uatkZPRAhVEDywKHQ62BNgQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=The%20reactions%20can%20be%20done%20in%20the%20gaseous%20phase%20dispersed%20in%20liquids.&f=false